# Mock subscription variable

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a variable called stateSubscrition$ which I use to hold and unsubscribe the subscription and it works well. But I need to know how to mock stateSubscription$ for writing unit test case for ondes

```
stateSubscription$: Subscription;
...
this.stateSubscription$ = this.updatedScheduleActivities$.subscribe((x) => {
  this.loadGrid();
});
...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.stateSubscription$.unsubscribe();
}
```

and in spec file

```
fdescribe('#onDestroy', () => {
    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
      component = new VariableComponent(mockStore, mockForm);
      spyOnProperty(component,'stateSubscription$','get').and.returnValue(Observable);
      component.ngOnDestroy();
    });

    it('should have called unsubscribe method', () => {
        expect(component.stateSubscription$.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

I'm getting error like this, how to mock this property ??

`Error: stateSubscription$ property does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

You can always initialize the `stateSubcription$`with an empty `Subscription`

```
stateSubscription$ = new Subscription();
```

That way you won't have to worry about `undefined` when accessing the property.